# How to specify multiple lexer rules in a single rule?

Tags: antlr, antlr4, language-recognition

I have the following parser rule:

```
declaration     : (KW_VARIABLE DT_IDENTIFIER) |
                  (KW_VARIABLE DT_IDENTIFIER OP_ASSIGNMENT DT_DATA_TYPES) OP_SEMICOLON;
```

and the following lexer rules:

```
KW_VARIABLE     : 'var';

OP_ASSIGNMENT   : '=';
OP_SEMICOLON    : ';';

DT_IDENTIFIER   : [a-z]+;
DT_INTEGER      : [0-9]+;
DT_DATA_TYPES   : (DT_IDENTIFIER | DT_INTEGER);
```

With the above rules, I want to be able to write the following code:

```
var a = 10;
var b = 40;
var c = 50;
var d = c;
```

My listener code for exiting declaration looks like this:

```
public override void ExitDeclaration([NotNull] PyroParser.DeclarationContext context)
{
    bool isAssigned = context.OP_ASSIGNMENT() != null;

    if (!isAssigned)
    {
        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(context.DT_DATA_TYPES().GetText());
    base.ExitDeclaration(context);
}
```

I get an error on the first line when I run saying:

> line 1:8 mismatched input '10' expecting DT_DATA_TYPES

I just want to be able to refer to all data types in a single rule, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This is incorrect:

```
DT_IDENTIFIER   : [a-z]+;
DT_INTEGER      : [0-9]+;
DT_DATA_TYPES   : (DT_IDENTIFIER | DT_INTEGER);
```

Once a `DT_IDENTIFIER` or `DT_INTEGER` is matched, it will never become a `DT_DATA_TYPES`. The lexer matches rules from top to bottom, and once a match is found, it will not give it up. And simply changing the order of the rules:

```
DT_DATA_TYPES   : (DT_IDENTIFIER | DT_INTEGER);
DT_IDENTIFIER   : [a-z]+;
DT_INTEGER      : [0-9]+;
```

will not work either: that way the lexer will never produce `DT_IDENTIFIER` and `DT_INTEGER` tokens.

You could do something like this instead:

```
dt_data_types   : (DT_IDENTIFIER | DT_INTEGER);

DT_IDENTIFIER   : [a-z]+;
DT_INTEGER      : [0-9]+;
```